# Change Timeout of Gunicorn Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn

I am trying to change the timeout for Gunicorn on a Python 3.7 Amazon Linux 2 (Version 3.1) Elastic Beanstalk deploy.  My Procfile looks like:

```
web: gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --threads 2 --timeout 300 application.application:application
```

But I still seem to be getting the default 30 second timeout.

My nginx config in .ebextensions looks like:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      keepalive_timeout 600;
      proxy_connect_timeout 600;
      proxy_send_timeout 600;
      proxy_read_timeout 600;
      send_timeout 600; 
      fastcgi_send_timeout 600; 
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue. I would like to ask a question about that. How can I configure procfile? Where did you added it in your source folder?

Comment: Create a file called Procfile in the root of your deployed application folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), setting `nginx` options through `/etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf` is **not supported**. This would explain why they don't have any effect.

For AL2, `nginx` settings **should be set** using `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` folder as show [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Thus, you could try the following. Have a file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with the content of:

```
keepalive_timeout 600;
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600; 
fastcgi_send_timeout 600; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
```

Comment: does this actually solve the problem of configuring gunicorn?